# Extract customSchemas values

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using AdminDirectory.Users.list() to pull a list of Directory attributes including some custom schema fields. Logging the output shows that all of the data is there however the custom schema fields are nested in the following format.
customSchemas={TVL={Date=1942-03-31, Vehicle_Reg=[{type=work, value=AB05CDE}, {type=work, value=FG06HIJ}]}},

How can I extract the individual values so that I can push them into a sheet?

Many thanks,

James P

Comment: To get a value out of a JSON object you need to use the dot operator and the name of the property (key)  A JSON object has elements with "key/value" pairs.  `var what_I_want = objectName.TVL.Date;` would get the `date` value for the `date` property (key).  `Vehicle_Reg` is in an array, and each element of the array is a JSON object.  To get an element out of an array, you must use an index number, and the index is zero based, so the first element is index 0.

Comment: You are asking a question about basic programming.  You should find a reference source for JavaScript rather than asking a question here on Stack Overflow for this type of question.  [JSON introduction](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp)

Comment: Thank you for your response but it is because neither standard dot or bracket notation appear to work in this instance that I am posting here.

Comment: `var schemas = users[i].customSchemas;` works and returns the correct value of {TVL={Date=1942-03-31, Vehicle_Reg=[{type=work, value=AB05CDE}, {type=work, value=FG06HIJ}]}}, however `var date = users[i].customSchemas.TVL.Date;` throws the following error TypeError: Cannot read property "TVL" from undefined.

Comment: You should have included in your question that dot and bracket notation are not working.  Check the data type of the variable.  If it's a string, you'll need to use `JSON.parse(object as string)` to convert the object as a string to a JSON object.  Use `typeof variable`  For example:  `if (typeof schemas === 'string') {schemas = JSON.parse(schemas);}`

Comment: Sorry Sandy, yes I should have been a bit more specific in the original post. I just assumed that as this was tagged as a google-apps-script topic that somebody else would have encountered the issue before. Thanks for your help and I will give your suggestion a try.